# How do I use $addToSet with condition in group?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate

I have the following documents:

```
_id: ObjectId('641316fd596514e63a2121ca'),
orgId: 3,
devices {
    _id: ObjectId('64131139596514e63a2121c1')
    name: 'Device A'
}
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('641316fd596514e63a2121ca'),
orgId: 3
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('64131b2b596514e63a2121ce'),
orgId: 4,
devices {
    _id: ObjectId('64131c1e596514e63a2121d0')
    name: 'Device B'
}
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('64131d38596514e63a2121d1'),
orgId: 5
```

---

```
_id: ObjectId('64131d38596514e63a2121d1'),
orgId: 5
```

From here I'm trying to group these documents by `_id` and `orgId`, and in that process add a new array of objects called **"endpoints"** that contains `type: 'linux'` and `refId: '$devices._id'`. But such object should **ONLY** be added to the array if the document has a devices field.

Like this:

```
_id: {
    id: ObjectId('641316fd596514e63a2121ca'),
    orgId: 3
},
endpoints: [
    type: 'windows',
    refId: ObjectId('64131139596514e63a2121c1')
]
```

---

```
_id: {
    id: ObjectId('64131b2b596514e63a2121ce'),
    orgId: 4
},
endpoints: [
    type: 'windows',
    refId: ObjectId('64131c1e596514e63a2121d0')
]
```

---

```
_id: {
    id: ObjectId('64131d38596514e63a2121d1'),
    orgId: 5
},
endpoints: [
]
```

This is what I've tried:

```
{
  $group: {
    _id: {
      id: '$_id',
      orgId: '$orgId',
    },
    endpoints: { 
      $addToSet: {
        $cond: {
          if: { 
            $ne: [ '$devices', undefined ] 
          },
          then: { 
            type: 'linux',
            refId: '$devices._id'
          },
          else: '$$REMOVE'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However I still get objects without "refId". like this:

```
_id: {
    id: ObjectId('64131d38596514e63a2121d1'),
    orgId: 5
},
endpoints: [
    {
        type: 'linux'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- `$eq` with `$type`: To check if the `devices.name` property is of type `string`. If the `devices` property does not exist, it will resolve to **false**.

```
$addToSet: {
  $cond: {
    if: { 
      $eq: [{ $type: '$devices.name' }, 'string'],
    },
    then: { 
      type: 'linux',
      refId: '$devices._id'
    },
    else: '$$REMOVE'
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried, it still does the same thing.

Comment: I updated my answer, can you try it again?

Comment: That was actually a genius way of doing it. Finally works!! Thank you very much!!